# Issue regarding vulnerability of cookies

Tags: cookies, protection

If someone somehow manages to copy all the cookies from my PC, can they be misused to get my private information or can information be extracted through them?

If yes, please suggest some countermeasures.

I am considering a situation when one gets all of my cookies through some utilities, like when I plug-in a USB drive (pen drive) of my friend or other colleague, and he just copies all the cookies through unfair means.

Method used--> By physically accessing the target system not through internet or any other network.
It is like copying all cookies of browser by using some utility to do it or copying manually.

Comment: Yes if someone got all your cookies they could be misused. Counter measures would be... not letting someone get all your cookies. What situation are you envisaging where someone has access to your cookies? What's the attack vector? It's a very broad question otherwise.

Comment: With the edit to include USB as the attack vector, the mitigation is to not plug a USB Drive that someone else has put files on into your PC. Or certainly not one from someone you can't trust. Really, your question isn't about cookies at this point. Cookie-specific attacks would be the likes of Cross Site Scripting (XSS). Your attack scenario is about stealing files from a machine that you have physical access to, or socially engineered access to. The mitigation of this is only ever going to be not allowing that access.

Comment: Divyanshu - any member of the community can downvote for any of the reasons given (eg not useful, no research effort etc). darkf is also providing useful comments to help you.

Comment: I agree with @darkf last comment. See the [10 immutable law of security](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh278941.aspx), the law #1 is that "*If a bad guy can persuade you to run his program on your computer, it's not solely your computer anymore.*", so yes he can steal your cookies, but it can also steal your files or delete them, install a keylogger, a remote access backdoor, spy your activity, impersonate you... However if you specially worry about your cookies just configure your browser to delete them upon shutdown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a user gets control over your cookies, he basically **impersonates you for (possibly) all open web sessions**, ie. websites you're logged into. You could pretty much compare a cookie with a key card for electronic entrance systems, if you hand this over to somebody, he will very be able to use it to get access. The only bad thing: key cards are harder to copy, and you're likely to realize if it was stolen.

**You cannot mitigate this** but by restricting access. If you *know* that your cookies have been copied, logout from all web sites you have cookies stored for. The website operator might have additional security measures in place (like coupling cookies to IP addresses or expiring the session after a while), but you cannot know whether he does but by testing yourself (and it might change over time).

The only countermeasure is: **don't let anybody use your computer (unsupervised)**, and encrypt your hard disk using a strong password (also add one for your user account) to prevent unsupervised access.

Comment: I added this as a counter-measure for webmasters next to the IP-address coupling, as it is very related.